# How do I get a type of a class at runtime with a string that inherits from an abstract class and use the retrieved type as a parameter

Tags: c#

How do I retrieve a class at `run-time` via string and still have the functionality of a generic like Example where ExampleAbstract: new()  ?

I get the error `Cannot convert type 'System.Type' to 'CodeStuff.Automobile' [ReminderCodeFolder]` when using Windows reflection to get the type.

```
public abstract class Automobile{
    public abstract void stuff();
}

public class Car : Automobile{
    public override void stuff(){
        Console.WriteLine("Nice");
    }
}

public class Program{
    public static void CarStuff(Automobile b){
        b.stuff();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args){
        Type ReadType = Type.GetType("CodeStuff.Car");
        CarStuff(Automobile(/*Solution*/))
    }
}
```

Comment: `CarStuff(Automobile(/*Solution*/))` - What's this supposed to mean in your code? If you had something like this in your code, you will get `Automobile` method does not exist in current context, not what you described in your question.

Comment: So you want to check in Car if it inherits from Automobile?

Comment: you need to 「return a String in public override string stuff() {...}」OR 「change to public abstract void stuff();」, then CarStuff(new Car()); will print out "nice"

Comment: No I want to use classes that inherit from an abstract class so I can execute the functions relative to the class like a generic but since The type parameter is only recieved at runtime because they are determined via windows reflection I can't use generics to do that.

Comment: Your example doesn't currently use generics. Do you mean that you want to instantiate a car object or a truck object based on a string value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CodeStuff
{
    public abstract class Automobile
    {
        public abstract void stuff();
    }
    public class Car : Automobile
    {
        public override void stuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nice");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void CarStuff(Automobile b)
        {
            b.stuff();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type ReadType = Type.GetType("CodeStuff.Car");
            Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(ReadType);
            CarStuff((Automobile)obj);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output : nice